# How does Android detect how fast the current Wi-Fi network is?

Tags: wi-fi, android-10

When going to `Settings` -> `Connections` -> `Wi-Fi`, Android displays the "network speed" of the current Wi-Fi network. I wonder how Android detects how fast the current Wi-Fi network is.

[image]

When I walk around, I see the speed changes:

[image]

I use Android 10 with Samsung Galaxy S9.

Comment: Does this help? https://kb.netgear.com/19668/Link-Rate-and-Transfer-Speed

Comment: @Firelord thank you this does help Good to know that this is called the link  rate, you are welcome to convert your comment into an answer

Comment: [RSSI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#calculateSignalLevel(int)) @Firelord if this helps in your answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15797920

Comment: Additional detail: Nexus 5 (Lineage OS 14.1, Android 7.1.2) uses "link speed" and Google Pixel 3a (Android 11) uses "transmit link speed".